# How to wait for a function in a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I am trying to learn promises. I think I understand how it works if you use if and else with resolve and reject, but what if I have a function that returns a value? How can I make a promise that runs the function and when it is done it takes the returned value as its resolve promise? Here is an example of what I am trying to do (the result is nothing):

```
function test() {
    return 'Hi'
}

function getData() {
    const inOrder = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        test()
    }).then((data)=> console.log('This is our data: ' + data))
}
```

Comment: `resolve( test( ) )`

Comment: Looking at [MDN's documentation for `Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve), we can see that it takes a value, that is then passed to the function given to `then`.

Comment: inOrder will be undefined

Comment: Ah, of course! I feel stupid now. But what if the return statement would take like 10 seconds or so, would it wait for it to finish?

Comment: @Hejhejhej123 If it's 10 seconds of synchronous JavaScript, then yes. If it's doing something asynchronous, then no. Hopefully it already returns a Promise and you don't need to construct one yourself, if not it should accept a callback function and you can use resolve as the callback function (or call it from the callback function)

Comment: @HereticMonkey - the documentation for `Promise.resolve` isn't going to help with the code in the question

Comment: @JaromandaX Let's leave the pedantics for more interesting questions, shall we?

Comment: Just to be clear here, there is no reason to wrap this purely synchronous function in a promise.  And, if it's purely synchronous, it doesn't make any difference whether it takes 1ms to finish or 30 seconds to finish.  Either way (wrapped in a promise or not), it will block the main JS thread while it's running and won't return until its done.   And, wrapping a purely synchronous operation in a promise just makes it more complicated to use - it's more complicated code than need be.

Comment: If it contains an asynchronous operation, then it needs to return a promise and still doesn't need to be wrapped in a promise.  The only time you would need to wrap it in a promise is if it's asynchronous and takes a plain callback for notification or asynchronous completion.  And, in that case, you would probably use `util.promisify()` (if this was node.js) rather than manually promisifying it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - that's not being pedantic, it's a fact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you need to resolve your promise

```js
function test() {
    return 'Hi'
}

(function getData() {
    const inOrder = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        resolve(test())
    }).then((data)=> console.log('This is our data: ' + data));
})();
```

Comment: @Hejhejhej123 - Just to be clear to the OP here.  There's no reason to wrap a purely synchronous function in a promise or even an asynchronous function that has no means of notifying of completion (as in the example in the original question).  This is a fine answer to the question as asked, it's just that the question is asking to do something that doesn't look like it needs to be done in the first place.